# How to avoid duplicating of PendingIntents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Hi!

I have a trouble with duplicating PendingIntents. My Application have Service that starts at application's onCreate, do some Async Task and stops by himself.
The problem is that on every application start I have a new set of PendingIntents from DB (exactly the same) in AlarmManager, but they don't cancel previous, even with FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT. I determine this by "adb shell dumpsys alarm",
Here is a onPostExecute of Async Task:
    protected void onPostExecute (Cursor c)
        {

```
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            int _id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Maindb._ID));
            long remind_timestamp = c.getLong(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Maindb.REMIND_TIMESTAMP));
            String remind_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Maindb.NAME));
            String remind_description = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Maindb.DESCRIPTION));

            Log.i("Service reminders : id = " + _id + "; REMIND_TIMESTAMP="
                    + remind_timestamp + "; NAME = " + remind_name
                    + "; DESCRIPTION=" + remind_description);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ReminderService.this,
                    AlarmReceiver.class);

            myIntent.putExtra(RemindDialog.REMIND_DIALOG_ID, _id);
            myIntent.putExtra(RemindDialog.REMIND_DIALOG_NAME, remind_name);
            myIntent.putExtra(RemindDialog.REMIND_DIALOG_DESCRIPTION,
                    remind_description);
            myIntent.putExtra(RemindDialog.REMIND_DIALOG_TIMESTAMP,
                    remind_timestamp);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ReminderService.this,
                    _id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, remind_timestamp,
                    pendingIntent);
            Log.i("Successfully setted alarm for ID:TIMESTAMP = " + _id
                    + ":" + remind_timestamp);


        }

        Log.d("Closing cursor");
        c.close();

        Log.d("Nothing else to do, Stoping the services by himself");
        stopSelf();

    }
```

The output from "adb shell dumpsys alarm" after second application launch look like:

> RTC_WAKEUP #26: Alarm{42096e70 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+93d9h0m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{4283e8b8: PendingIntentRecord{426ab530 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #25: Alarm{41dff7f8 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+93d9h0m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{41f1e730: PendingIntentRecord{41e7e1b0 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #24: Alarm{42161b60 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+76d19h50m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{428494d8: PendingIntentRecord{42705b90 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #23: Alarm{41ef50a8 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+76d19h50m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{41f1de18: PendingIntentRecord{41efdcd0 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #22: Alarm{42549b40 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+51d5h30m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{428697e8: PendingIntentRecord{427c9890 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #21: Alarm{41f2fe20 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+51d5h30m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{41fb31a0: PendingIntentRecord{41f3d018 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #20: Alarm{4269f008 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+21d10h30m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{428706f0: PendingIntentRecord{427fd1f0 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #19: Alarm{41fb1428 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+21d10h30m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{41f3c958: PendingIntentRecord{4212d098 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #18: Alarm{426aa948 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+16d14h16m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{42875fb8: PendingIntentRecord{4282bf98 com.startService}}
>
> RTC_WAKEUP #17: Alarm{42554a70 type 0 com.}
>      type=0 when=+16d14h16m54s107ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
>      operation=PendingIntent{41ec39e8: PendingIntentRecord{426a0620 com.startService}}

So, the main question is why my PendingIntents duplicating, because on the first look, first and second launch should do absolutely the same (input Cursor definitely the same).

Thanks! Sorry for my English.

Comment: Is your `_id` always the same? Because you will get a different `PendingIntent` for each different value of `_id`.

Comment: @David Wasser Yes, _id are the same. I retrieve it from sqlite DB. And I rechecked this two times with logs.

Comment: Well, you could try to cancel the alarms first before rescheduling them (see my answer). Let me know if that solves it.

Comment: @David Wasser cancelling didn't work, pending intents still duplicating

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. Please try this and let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>You may have replaced the `PendingIntent` so that you don't have duplicates. However, you have not cancelled the alarm that you previously scheduled with the `AlarmManager`. To do that you need to call:</strike>

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

before doing:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, remind_timestamp, pendingIntent);
```

This will cancel any alarms that match the passed `PendingIntent`.

**EDIT: Above answer was no help to OP and is probably wrong (see comment from A--C)**

You need to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when replacing the `PendingIntent`. This should result in only 1 scheduled Alarm.

The problem is that by cancelling the existing `PendingIntent` when you create a new one, you make it impossible for the `AlarmManager` to determine that the alarm you are scheduling is replacing another one (because it cannot compare the `PendingIntent` because the old one is no longer there).

Comment: [`set()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) should automatically do the replacing. *If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled, then it will be removed and replaced by this one*

Comment: @A--C Yep, you're right there. I had forgotten about that :-( Looking at the code the only other thing I can think of is that his "_id" field is always different, but in the description he implies that it isn't.